# Import Error When Switchin from Python 2.7 to Python 3.4 on Heroku running django-oscar on django 1.7.6

Tags: python, django, heroku, wsgi, python-3.4

Somewhat similar issue to [this one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/django-oscar/python$203.4$20django$201.7$20import$20error/django-oscar/BNBI2xgPm0o/Dd24lzpPQGwJ) although not quite. Installation was running fine on Heroku and Python 2.7 and also fine with Python 3.4 on my dev machine (OS X). Regretfully switched over to Python 3.4 on Heroku as well and am now getting

```
 Django Version:    1.7.6
 Exception Type:    ImportError
 Exception Value: cannot import name 'shop' in urls.py  in <module>, line 5
```

Oscar is installed in the virtual env and imports without a problem from the shell

wsgi.py looks as follows:

```
 import os
 os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "super_secret_project.settings")`

 from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
 # from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
 application = get_wsgi_application()
 # application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

I tried force loading models with an added dummy import in urls.py:
`from oscar.apps.order import models`

Starting to think it might be an issue with Heroku/wsgi files

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by importing this way:

```
from oscar.app import application as shop
```